# I Want to create a 24hrs timeline chart

Tags: excel, powershell, google-visualization

I have written a PowerShell script which extracts the system on/off time for the  previous one month. I am storing all this data in a list.

I want to create a kind of chart which will have date on y-axis and timeline i.e(12:00 Am to 23:00 pm) on x-axis, like this one: [image: picture]

I have created this kind of chart using Google Charts, here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kx7mz16p/1/)`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});`
for that. The problem with this is I can't share this chart on a mail to users.

I was also trying to create this kind of chart in excel but with no success.

so please can anyone suggests me or point me towards something which can be used to create this kind of chart and share with the users on email.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MS Chart Controls](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422), which will allow you to create a chart programmatically, then save as an image, which you can then attach to an email.

[This example](https://bytecookie.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/tutorial-powershell-and-microsoft-chart-controls-or-how-to-spice-up-your-reports/), with code below, shows how to make a bar chart.

*This is not code you can use 'as-is'*.

Read on for more info on how to use this as a basis for creating the chart type you want.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization")
$scriptpath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

# chart object
$chart1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

$chart1.Width = 600
$chart1.Height = 600
$chart1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::White

# title
[void]$chart1.Titles.Add("Top 5 - Memory Usage (as: Column)")
$chart1.Titles[0].Font = "Arial,13pt"
$chart1.Titles[0].Alignment = "topLeft"

# chart area 
$chartarea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$chartarea.Name = "ChartArea1"
$chartarea.AxisY.Title = "Memory (MB)"
$chartarea.AxisX.Title = "Process Name"
$chartarea.AxisY.Interval = 100
$chartarea.AxisX.Interval = 1
$chart1.ChartAreas.Add($chartarea)
```

The C# example in [**this link**](http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2010/05/15/creating-a-gantt-chart-with-the-microsoft-chart-controls.aspx) shows how to build a Gantt chart, which is what I think you want, based on your example.

So, you now need to combine the C# Gantt code, with the PowerShell code, to create your Gantt in PowerShell.

[This link](https://learn-powershell.net/2016/09/18/building-a-chart-using-powershell-and-chart-controls/), shows some more PowerShell charting and also shows how to **save a chart**:

```
$chart1.SaveImage('C:\temp\chart.jpeg', 'jpeg')
```